# Null as an array element in C/C++

Tags: c, arrays

I want to have `\0` as one of my array (char type) element in my  C/C++ code but not the last one.
I am doing this.

```
char arr[10]  ; //array declaration
//initializing the array
arr[0] = 'a'  ;
arr[1] = '\0' ;
arr[2] = 's'  ;
```

When i try printing these array elements, i get some symbolic stuff as output for `a[1]`.
I guess 0 is converted to char. Is that so ?
If yes, can't i have `\0` anyhow in my array before the termination ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are either compiling C or compiling C++. Pick one to write, pick one to tag your question with. The languages can be quite different, and more so with more modern versions.

Comment: @crashmstr In this case both are valid. Why pick one, when you get exactly the same results in both? Usually I make exactly the same comment as you, but here it is actually appropriate to tag both.

Comment: "I guess 0 is converted to char". That already happened when you stored it in a `char` array.

Comment: @crashmstr But that won't make a difference in my case.

Comment: @luk32 I think it is a bad habit to think "C/C++" as a single language, even for cases where there is no difference. If you have a question about using a C library in a C++ program, then certainly both tags make sense.

Comment: @crashmstr I think you went overboard and make a case where there is no case. You want OP to compiler with a `c` compiler and `c++` compile to prove he can tag with both? Yes thinking `c` and `c++` as one is bad. Forcefully separating them where it is not appropriate on this basis is just as wrong to me.

Comment: '\0' is not converted to char, it is a char (at least in C++)

Comment: @user3061829 true, but there is no language called "C/C++". See the question on [meta re: Suggestion: New C/C++ Tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145328/1441)

Comment: well guys, is there any way to have what i want?

Comment: @crashmstr Do you see this "There might be a couple of valid usages, but are largely irrelevant to the tag system." in the very post you link to? This is a case. And I still agree in general it's a bad habit to think it's the same.

Comment: If you found any of these answers helpful you may want to consider [accepting one of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour i still am not clear how to solve my problem, i din't find any of the answers worth for this particular question.

Comment: @user3061829 that is reasonable, have you considered asking for clarification from one of the answers? It may also help if you provide a complete program that demonstrates the problem, for this question that should not require many additional lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

`'/0'` is not a null character. Escaping uses a backslash: `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can have `\0` in an array as same as other values and it's OK.

The problem is you can not print it due to two reasons:

1. It terminates printing in `cout` and `printf` because they assume `\0` means end of the string.
2. `\0` is not a printable character.

So, you should write your own function to print the array that prints something as `\0` and doesn't terminate the string when reaches to it. (So, you should indicate the end of string by something else)

For example:

```
void print(const std::string &s)
{
    for (auto x : s)
        std::cout << ((x == '\0')? '.' : x);
}

int main( )
{
    std::string s {'a','\0','s'};
    print(s);
}
```

Output:

> a.s

It prints a dot instead of that non-printable value.

*Note: The OP was tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) also.*

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function like this:

```
void print(char *arr, int length){
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(arr[i] != '\0')
           printf("%c",arr[i]);
        else
           printf("\\0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid to have a `'\0'` in your (`char`) array but all the standard functions assume that it indicates the end of the array. So to print a (non-c-)string like this you need  your own function. For example:

```
void myPuts(size_t length, char * str){
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        putchar(str[i]);
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
myPuts(10, arr);
```